# How to get the sender's email address from Outlook?

Tags: c#, .net

I have write the code for reading inbox messages from the outlook by using exchange server. below are the code for reading.

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, itemview);
```

the results get successfully. But not getting the sender's Email address in that results. How to get the sender's Email address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should cast the `Item` to a [EmailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage_properties%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) and then you can view the `From` property.

So for example:

```
var mailItems = findResults.Where(x => x is EmailMessage).Cast<EmailMessage>().ToList();

foreach (EmailMessage item in mailItems)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.From.Address);
}
```

Comment: In which namespace MailItem Class present?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_members.aspx

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` - I figured that's what you're using, am I wrong?